# Get absolute path of resource file inside a jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, jar

I want to access a file inside a resource folder of the current jar running.
The file is inside of `My_app.jar` where is located to `/apps/dashboard/`
I tried to access it like this

```
String customScriptPath = "script/template.sh";
public String getTemplatePath() {
        Resource temp=  new ClassPathResource(this.customScriptPath, this.getClass().getClassLoader()); 
        try {
            File templateFile =  temp.getFile();
            logger.info("Script template path = "+templateFile.getAbsolutePath());
            return templateFile.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and I got this error

```
class path resource [script/template.sh] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/apps/dashboard/My_app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/script/template.sh
```

Comment: Take a look at something called: `getResourceAsStream`. Here you can find sample where file from `JAR` is extracted into filesystem. In your case, you can simply read it: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/blob/master/recipes/recipeNo035/java/recipeNo035/Main.java - take a look at method: `extractLibrary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `File` to access the `template.sh`. `File` is used to reference files in the file system. In your case, you are trying to reference something inside a jar file.

If you want to read content of `template.sh`, take a stream using `Resource.getInputStream()`. If you want to log location of the file, use `Resource.getURL()`.